# AngularJS Controller File Download On Demand

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm new to angular but as far as my understanding that all controller file(s)' content need to be sent to the client in the beginning of the page.

What if we have a lot of controllers in the application?

This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) mentions that combining angularjs and requirejs is the solution, also there is a [seed project](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed) that use both.
On that article states that

> While this type of code works great for defining routes it requires
>   controller scripts to be loaded upfront in the main shell page by
>   default. That works fine in some scenarios but what if you have a lot
>   of controller scripts and views in a given application and want to
>   dynamically load them on-the-fly at runtime?

I confuse with this part, "load them dynamically", does it mean that the controller file(s)' content will still be downloaded / sent to the client, but it will be loaded on demand or does it also include downloading file content on demand part?

My concern is that if initial loading takes too long, the application will fail. This situation happened in the last project when we built xbap application and internet connection is not something reliable, for example in the RIG site.

CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I understand "load them dynamically" as you mentioned have 2 steps in the process, one is to "download" the file to the client that's the reason you are using requireJS:

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.

That means that you can download the files to the client on demand depending on your different scenarios, in the article depends on the route you are reaching something that really makes sense.

The other step is to include your controller into an angularjs app that has been already bootstrapped, that's a lazy loading and accomplished by the  **$controllerProvider**.

PS:
obviously if you include a reference of the JS file in your index file, the file will be downloaded no matter what.

Comment: @jack-the-ripper could you please provide link about lazy loading angularjs?

Comment: it's on the article you describe earlier, the logic of the lazy loading resides on the routeResolver.js section!

Comment: this is a very similar approach to the onde you mentioned in the article, cheers! http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/